# Algorithm for permutations

Tags: php

I am looking for an **efficient** combinations function  that would take into account the order of the array. For example I want to generate all of the combinations of "hello world" but I don't want any of it reversed "world hello". I currently have a combinations function but it's too much.

Simple example :

```
$text = "Hello World"
$arr = explode(" ",$text); // string to array
```

And gives:

```
$result = combo_function($arr);
var_dump($result);

"Hello World"
"Hello" 
"World"
```

I do NOT want the inverse:

```
"World Hello"
```

- the key is that I want it to be faster than combinations if possible.

Currently I am using this:

```
 // careful, this is very labor intensive ( O(n^k) )

public function buildSearchCombinations(&$set, &$results)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($set); $i++) {

        $results[] = (string) $set[$i];
        $tempset = $set;
        array_splice($tempset, $i, 1);
        $tempresults = array();
        $this->buildSearchCombinations($tempset, $tempresults);

        foreach ($tempresults as $res) {
            $results[] = trim((string) $set[$i]) . " " . (string) trim($res);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "combination of hello world"? All combinations of the order of your words?

Comment: it's really unclear what you want to accomplish here! your example hello world is really poor to understand what are you trying to do!

Comment: Basically I am trying to create a set of permutations to use in a Database search but instead of using ALL combinations, we can assume that the user has to enter them in order. So for example if they are searching "French Fries"  it will return say all of the restaurants serving them. Where if they were to enter in Fries French, it will fail. Currently I am using combinations which will automatically generate "French Fries" and "Fries French" along with "Fries" and "French". This is too much work with larger phrases.

Comment: Answer to your [deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42768694/3776858): [How can I sort an Apache log file by date?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6137712/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a rather odd solution to this:

```
<?php

function supersetmember($set, $index) {
    $keys = array_reverse(str_split(decbin($index)));
    $member = [];
    foreach ($keys as $k => $v) {
        if ($v == 1) { 
            $member[] = $set[$k];
        }

    }
    return $member;
}


$text = "Hello World";
$arr = explode(" ",$text);
$total = pow(2,count($arr)); //Total permutations on size of set n is 2^n 
$superset = [];
for ($i = 0;$i < $total;$i++) {
    $superset[] = supersetmember($arr,$i);
}
print_r($superset);
```

Explanation:

There's 2^n sets that constitute a set of size n (including the empty set).
You can map each of those sets as a natural number from 0 to (n-1). 
If you convert that number to binary then the digits that are 1 will indicate which members of the original set your subset will contain. Example:

Set = (A,B);

Superset member 2(decimal) = 10 (binary) which means the subset will include the 
second but not first member (we read the number from right to left as in from least significant to most significant digit).

The advantage of doing this is that you have a sort of a "fausset" algorithm (function supersetmember) which you give it a set and the subset you want and you get that subset.

The complexity of getting a single subset in the current version is `O(n)` but if you implement it with bit shifting you can reduce it to `O(log n)` In total the algorithm will be `O(2^n)` which is unavoidable because there are `O(2^n)` subsets to be generated.

Comment: Wow dude, this is totally badass

Comment: @MikeQ if you want to share how you used this code, the generally accepted convention here is to update your question.

Comment: ok thx, I forgot that I should have done it that way... I blame it on it being the weekend. thanks